# CSS float: left causing unnecessary whitespace with varying height

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is a problem with a live website, the page I'm talking about is [this](http://continuumtrio.co.uk/gallery.php).

Basically I have some PHP which echos out images from my db wrapped in divs, like this, for example, for each image:

```
<div class='gall_div'>
<a href='img_gallery/CD cover Bach 2.jpg' class='lightbox'>
<img class='galleryImage' title='(tooltip)' src='someimg.jpg'>
</a></div>
```

I want my images to wrap to the left, the CSS looks like this:

```
div.gall_div {
    float:left;
    margin-right:120px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-top:10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Notice, if you try resizing the page, unnecessary whitespace appears to the left of the second/third row of images. I believe this is due to varying image height. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the best solution here would be to change your CSS slightly, to declare them as `inline-block` elements, and have the text-align set to the left:

```
div.gall_div {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:120px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-top:10px;
    text-align:left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Additionally, this allows you to set `vertical-align: middle;` so that they can be vertically centered, if need be.